# railsでフォルダごとダウンロードできる機能を実装したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby on railsを使って現在ダウンロード機能を実装しています。構想では、フォルダごとダウンロードできるようにしたいと考えていますが、このようなことは可能でしょうか？
参考webサイトを探してもなく、自分で、フォルダを指定して実行してみてもできなかったので教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「フォルダごと」は zip などでアーカイブして1ファイルをダウンロード。でよろしいですか?

Comment: すみません。zip形式にしておくなどは考えていませんでした。
ただ、そのような方法でもいいので、フォルダの中に入ってあるものをダウンロードできるようにしたいと考えています。

Comment: zip形式に変換して行う方法で考えてみたいと思います。
ありがとうございます。